# Why is nullmailer appending my hostname to the recipient address?

Tags: email

I want to set up nullmailer to relay mail to my provider's SMTP.

Since the provider drops email with mismatching sender's domain and user login, I used `/etc/nullmailer/allmailfrom` to match the login from `/etc/nullmailer/remotes` and it works, I can send email to fully qualified addresses.

I also used `/etc/nullmailer/adminaddr` to redirect all local emails `[user]@localhost` to `default@myowndomain.net`. This is because according to `man nullmailer-queue`

> ```
>    adminaddr
>           If this file is not empty, all recipients to users at either
>           "localhost" (the literal string) or the canon‐
>           ical host name (from /etc/mailname ) are remapped to this 
>           address.  This is provided to allow local daemons
>           to be able to send email to "somebody@localhost" and have it go
>           somewhere sensible instead of being bounced
>           by your relay host. To send to multiple addresses, put them all
>           on one line separated by a comma.
> ```

Now I want to have `myowndomain.net` appended to generic usernames (`mail any_username`). According to `man nullmailer-inject`,

> ```
>    defaultdomain
>           The  content  of  this file is appended to any host name that
>           does not contain a period (except localhost),
>           including defaulthost and idhost.  Defaults to the value of the
>           /etc/mailname system file,  if  it  exists,
>           otherwise the literal name defauldomain.
>
>    defaulthost
>           The  content of this file is appended to any address that is
>           missing a host name.  Defaults to the value of
>           the /etc/mailname system file, if it exists, otherwise the
>           literal name defaulthost.
> ```

From what I understood, I should use `/etc/nullmailer/defaulthost` because I am sending emails to addresses missing a host name. Therefore I placed there `myowndomain.net`.

However, nullmailer still appends `@hostname.myprovider.net`, resulting in emails dropped by the SMTP relay host: said domain does not exist.

How can I configure nullmailer to just add `@myprovider.net` instead of `@hostname.myprovider.net` to addresses missing a hostname?